# Running local (reactor) maven plugin from command line

Tags: java, maven

I have a seemingly very simple issue that I am trying to solve, however even after hours of trying and searching I cant seem to find a reasonable answer.

Consider the following maven project module setup (say group id is org.example and version is 1.0):

```
-A
|-B
|-C
 |-D
 |-E <--- maven plugin
```

So my submodule C has two submodules of which one (E) is a maven plugin. I am now in the root directory (of A) and am trying to invoke a mojo of E via CLI and I am unable to do so. I tried the following:

```
mvn E:my-mojo
mvn E:my-mojo -pl C/E -am
mvn org.example:E:1.0:my-mojo
mvn org.example:E:my-mojo
```

The first two result in the error that there is no plugin with the prefix `E`. The two other versions attempt to download `org.example:E:1.0` or `org.example:E` respectively from our package mirror, which of course fails because it is local and not distributed.

Is it possible to invoke my plugin just via CLI? It works when I add my plugin for example to module B inside the `<build/>` configuration.

Comment: So did you run a build like `mvn clean verify` first?

Comment: Yes, I also tried to use the plugin as a plugin in module `B` properly used via `<build><plugins><plugin><artifactId>E</artifactId><groupId>org.example</groupId><version>1.0</version><execution>...</execution></plugin></plugins></build>` and it gets properly invoked